# Extjs: how to render a progress bar with a tooltip in a grid

Tags: javascript, extjs, grid, progress-bar

I have a grid and one of the columns prepresents a progress bar. I need to set a tooltip "Progress 4 of 10" over the progress bar. Initially it was like this:

```
columns: [
        {
        translatable: {
            text: 'progress'
        },
        tdCls: 'highlight',
        xtype: 'widgetcolumn',
        dataIndex: 'progress',
        widget: {
            cls: 'percentage-bar',
            text: ' ',
            align: 'center',
            xtype: 'progressbar',
            defaultListenerScope: true,
            listeners: {
                afterrender: function (bar) {
                    var tip = Ext.create('Ext.tip.ToolTip', {
                        target: bar,
                        html: Dict.translateAndReplace(
                            'step',
                            [
                                bar.getWidgetRecord().get('current_step') === 0 ? 1 : bar.getWidgetRecord().get('current_step'),
                                bar.getWidgetRecord().get('total_steps')
                            ],
                            '%d'
                        )
                    });

                    if (bar.getValue() === 1) {
                        bar.addCls('progress-complete')
                    }
                },
            },
        },
        width: 100
    },
```

The issue is - it works only for a single page. When there are several pages or I apply filtering or sorting, event "afterrender" is not triggered. So it's triggred only then the grid is loaded, not the content. I need either to change to target element or use renderer. I tried to play arroung with renderer, but also stuck. How to get current cell container?

```
    columns: [
        {
        translatable: {
            text: 'progress'
        },
        tdCls: 'highlight',
        xtype: 'widgetcolumn',
        dataIndex: 'progress',
        width: 100,
        widget: {
            cls: 'percentage-bar',
            text: ' ',
            align: 'center',
            xtype: 'progressbar',
            defaultListenerScope: true,
        },
        renderer: function (value, metaData, record) {
            let HowToGetTheContainer = "?????";
            var tip = Ext.create('Ext.tip.ToolTip', {
                target: HowToGetTheContainer,
                html: Dict.translateAndReplace(
                    'step',
                    [
                        record.get('current_step') === 0 ? 1 : record.get('current_step'),
                        record.get('total_steps')
                    ],
                    '%d'
                )
            });

            if (value === 1) {
                Ext.down().addCls('progress-complete')
            }

        }
    },
```

How to get that variable "HowToGetTheContainer"?

Answer (score 0):

Within the `renderer` function, you can add a tooltip with this code (this works on other column types as well, not only on `widgetcolumn`):

```
metaData.tdAttr = Ext.String.format('data-qtip="{0}"', 'This is my tooltip here');
```

This was not a part of your question, but to customise the widget in the `widgetcolumn`, for example to add the `progress-complete` style, instead of using `Ext.down()`, you can use the `onWidgetAttach` function of the column:

```
columns: [{
    xtype: 'widgetcolumn',    
    onWidgetAttach: function(col, widget, record) {        
        widget.setIconCls('xxx')
        widget.addCls('xxx')
        widget.setText('xxx');
        // etc
    },    
}]
```